# symfony FOS not installing

Tags: symfony

Trying to install symfony FOS Bundle gives me error :

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~1.3"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6, v1.3.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.0 requires symfony/security-bundle 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.3.10, required as 3.3.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.3.10].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

So at first the error that it gave me was that my version of PHP(7.0.1) is too low for symfony 3.3 and it has to be atleast => 7.0.8 .

So I uninstalled xampp , but saved htdocs as backup , got 7.1.10 and tried again , this was the time when I noticed that one laravel project in netbeans started having an error and the symfony project too .

So I tried installing FOS , this error pops up now , updated my composer , because I thought it is from not updated version of composer , but it is not that obviously , because the error is the same .

I saw another post but it was not the same problem , so I thought of asking for help here , because I am new to this .

But I understood that my life will be easier if I have FOS Bundle , so I really want it to start .

So please help me , what should I do ?
P.S. I have just cutted my htdocs folder from desktop and pasted it in xampp dir and replaced the elements .

This is my composer.json in the symfony project:

```
 {
    "name": "/docsite",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    }
}
```

My php version :

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.10 (cli) (built: Sep 26 2017 20:07:27) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

And the last command :

```
echo %path%
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Вълкови\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Liquid Technologies\Liquid Studio 2017\XmlDataBinder15\Redist15\cpp\win32\bin;C:\Program Files\Liquid Technologies\Liquid Studio 2017\XmlDataBinder15\Redist15\cpp\win64\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Users\Вълкови\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Вълкови\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\xampp\php\php.exe;
```

Comment: Could you share the following? I'm sure it will help anyone who wants to chime in to understand exactly the problem you're facing: (1) Your `composer.json` file, (2) the output of typing `php -v` at the command line, and (3) the output of `echo $PATH` at the command line.

Comment: @CameronHurd I did it , thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is FOSUser 1.3 does not work with Symfony 3.3, you have to use FOSUser 2.0 and install it like:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"
```

And that should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes , it did ! :)